# What would be a formula for this?

Tags: arithmetic

I'm trying to find a formula for this scenario:

I need \$$302$.

I gain \$$2$ every second.

I gain \$$5$ every $5$ seconds.

When will I reach \$$302$? Both of these rates are working together.

Visually:

```
$2 $2 $2 $2 ($2 $5) $2 $2 $2 $2 ($2 $5)
```

I'm able to find the answer by diving by \$$15$ and figuring out how many sequences there were, but I'm looking for an equation.

$302 / 15 = ~20$

$20$ x $5$s + $1$s = $101$s

Comment: 1. Find the LCM of $2$ seconds and $5$ seconds, which is $10$ seconds. 2. Calculate the amount of money that you make during those $10$ seconds. 3. Divide $302$ dollars by that amount. BTW, if you're looking for an equation, then we're looking for variable names, which you haven't specified in your question.

Comment: @barakmanos sorry i meant $302

Comment: @barakmanos thought there would be an equation for this like summation of rates or something like that

Comment: You've already written an equation for your specific values. If you want a general equation, then you need to specify general names for your values (a.k.a *variables*).

Comment: On average you get 3 dollars per second. After 100 seconds you get 300 dollars. At the second 101 you get your last 2 dollars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After $n$ seconds you have $2n+5\left\lfloor \frac{n}{5} \right\rfloor$ dollars. Now you want to find $n$ for which
$$302 \leq 2n+5\left\lfloor \frac{n}{5} \right\rfloor$$
and since $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{5} \right\rfloor \leq \frac{n}{5}$ you have
$$302 \leq 2n+5\frac{n}{5}=3n$$
so $n\geq 101$.

Here $\left\lfloor .\right\rfloor$ is the floor function.

Comment: so this is like LCM, only it's relative to 1 second. this seems more like a rule than an equation?

Comment: oh i get it, the floor is what I'm looking for

Comment: You can turn it into general inequality, if you replace $302$ with some variable.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what i'm looking for.

Comment: You are welcome.